# How to find size of db.Model instances in GAE Python before calling db.put()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm writing an optimizer for my application, so db.put() invoked as rarely as possible. I stuck with following problem:

I have a number of classes derived from db.Model. The instances of those classes stored in list:

```
class DBPutter:
    data = [] # list of instances
    def add(self, model):
        # HERE I WANT TO CHECK THAT self.data IS NOT EXEEDING 1MB
        self.data.append(model)
        if len(self.data) == 1000:
            self.flush()  # actual call to db.put() using deferred
```

With this approach I receive alot of `RequestTooLargeError` exceptions. How do I check that my data is not exeeding 1MB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pympler has a asizeof method, and should run in python 2.5: http://code.google.com/p/pympler/

I think you're over-optimizing though. If an instance is shut down before 1000 objects are in your putter you could lose data.  Also, I think using the deferred library with a large amount of data would result in at least two db.puts.  One when the task is submitted (because the payload is over 10k), and one inside the task, actually writing your models.

Comment: thanks for `pympler` link. As for deferred - there is nothing bad will happen, because deferred procedure takes "what to put" from memcache, which is 1MB limited too.

Comment: According to the docs it writes it to the datastore: "If you try to enqueue a task that is too big to fit on the queue by itself, the deferred library will automatically create a new Entity in the _datastore_ to hold information about the task, and will delete the entity once the task has been run."

Comment: deferred receives only key, and the data itself is stored in memcache. Also, I tried the variant with storing whole batch into intermediate blob - almost no performance degrade (around 40ms per big batch)

Comment: I still say it's a bad idea. Your data could be evicted from memcache (or fail to store) at any time, even in the 0.1 seconds between putting it in memcache and running your task.

Answer (score 3):

As per the 1.4.0 release notes:

- Size and quantity limits on datastore batch get/put/delete operations have been removed. Individual entities are still limited to 1 MB, but your app may batch as many entities together for get/put/delete calls as the overall datastore deadline will allow for.

That said, using deferred for this is pointless: Task Queue payloads are limited to 10k, and if your deferred payload is bigger than that, it will create a datastore entity to store the payload in. As a result, it's doing a datastore operation anyway, so you may as well do it yourself.

If you're storing thousands of entities, though, you almost certainly want to be doing the whole process on the task queue in the first place, rather than in an interactive request.

Comment: You're getting that because `deferred` tries to pickle your list of entities and put them all into a single datastore entry. Then it takes them out of the datastore when the task is run, unpickles them, and then puts them _again_ individually.

Comment: @Calvin argument of deferred is a key, not batch. The batch is stored separately so there is no second put. But anyway now I see WHY I got that exception :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with GAE, but you could try to call sys.getsizeof on each of your models and verify that the sum is less than 1 MB.

Edit: See this [ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/546530/) for an alternative to sys.getsizeof, which should work in Python 2.5.

Comment: GAE uses Python 2.5, but sys.getsizeof exists in Python 2.6 and higher

Comment: I'm sure there are 3rd party solutions for <2.6 :)